# C# equivalent of Substring & Patindex of Sql server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-core

I have the following SQL Server code which I would like to do in C# code.
The logic is - to remove leading zeros
please help me to translate the code into C#.

```
DECLARE @TESTVariable as varchar(500)
Set @TESTVariable = '00013025990'

SELECT Substring(@TESTVariable, Patindex('%[^0 ]%', @TESTVariable + ' '), Len(@TESTVariable))
```

output expected

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| '001' | '1' |
| '00' | '0' |
| '00013025990' | '13025990' |

Comment: `str.TrimStart('0')`

Comment: Look at TrimStart. Again, if there are only zeros it will return empty, so add a check for it in your code TrimStart('0')

Answer (score 3):

1. `String.TrimStart(Char)` method is used to remove specified character from leading edge of the current string.

   ```
    string s= "00013025990";
    var result = s.TrimStart('0');
   ```
2. or convert the string to a number so that the zeros are removed from the beginning (this method is correct for the `zero character` only)

   ```
   var result=int.Parse(s);
   ```

If you want to get `'0' from '00'`, the `TrimStart` is not correct and you have to use the second way.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than convert the T-SQL code directly to roughly .NET equivalents, consider using the [String.TrimStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart) method for this task.

```
var TESTVariable = "00013025990";
Console.WriteLine(TESTVariable.TrimStart('0'));
```

I see from your edit you may have a zero value you want to preserve. If the string values are integers, you can use `Parse` and `ToString` to remove leading zeros except for the last:

```
Console.WriteLine(Int64.Parse("001").ToString("0"));
Console.WriteLine(Int64.Parse("00").ToString("0"));
Console.WriteLine(Int64.Parse("00013025990").ToString("0"));
```